# Getting error while running bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am following this article where I can written this code in this ruby file below and home page does have sample app, but it still says static pages home page should have content 'Sample App' when I run `bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`

**spec/requests/static_pages_spec file code:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      page.should have_content('Sample App')
    end
  end
end
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<h1>Sample App</h1>
<p>
  This is the home page for the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  sample application.
</p>
```

**Below is my gem file for this app. please advise. thanks for your help.**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'
gem 'sqlite3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
group :development do
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.0'

end

group :test do
gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
gem 'capybara', '1.0.0.beta1'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'


group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment: Can you post the output from the rspec run?

Comment: Try changing `page.should have_content('Sample App')` to `page.should have_content("Sample App")`

Comment: You can `puts page.content` in the spec to check what you're getting instead of the page you're expecting. That should give you an idea what's wrong. If that doesn't help show us your routes file, the problem may be there.

Comment: Posting Output in 2 comments:C:\rails\Sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
You must use ANSICON 1.31 or later (http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon/) to use colo
ur on Windows
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directlyin #<Class:0x3599a18> instead. (called from <top (required)> at C:/rails/Sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:3)
F Failures:

Comment: Adding Remaining output:            1) Static pages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
     Failure/Error: page.should have_content('Sample App')
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find xpath "/html"
     # (eval):2:in `text'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (requ
ired)>'

Finished in 4.49 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:7 # Static pages Home page should hav
e the content 'Sample App'

Comment: I also tried "Sample App" but did not workeither.  Also tried to replace  page.should have_content('Sample App') with page.content but did not work either. Any thoughts please?

Comment: Posting C:\rails\Sample_app\config\routes.rb file below: SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "static_pages/home"
get "static_pages/help" end   (Everyhting else is commented out in this file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the output from your failed rspec test do you have the line `FATAL:  database "sample_app_test" does not exist` many lines above the error `Failed examples: rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:7 # Static pages Home page should have the content 'Ruby on Rails'`? If so the following steps worked for me:

Open the `sample_app/config.database.yml` file in a text editor, and under `test`, change the database to the actual name of the postgres db you using, save the .yml file, and re-run the rspec test.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to require capybara manualy in the `spec_helper.rb`. That's what I normally do :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a conflict with webrat. Remove it from you gem file.

```
#gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
gem 'capybara', '1.0.0.beta1'
```